# HangerFire shows 404 error in Production server while deleting faile jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, production-environment, hangfire

When I am trying to delete the failed jobs in the production server i am getting 404 error but I am able to delete them in my local PC.

URL
https://mywebsite.com/hangfire/jobs/failed/delete
HTTP ERROR 404

URL
https://localhost:59141/hangfire/jobs/failed/delete
HTTP 200

Can anyone let me know why this is happening on the production server only.
There is only one server behind this url..
Thanks in Advance…

Comment: You tried something like this: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/dashboard-returns-404-for-application/633/6

Comment: actually the url is not pointing to the solution i am looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually I am facing was -  I deployed the hangfire application inside the sharepoint website in IIS.

The path deleting the job was something like this on button click

http://SharePointWebsite/MyAapplicationWebSite/hangfire/jobs/failed/delete

This is the path that is getting generated by the hangfire code internally(I added the hangfire assembly reference to my project). My Share Point application due to some configuration issues is not accepting this huge path. So i changed the path to 
http://SharePointWebsite/MyAapplicationWebSite/hangfire/jobs/faileddelete

(I removed one "/" in the path) which worked for me.

How to change automatic generated path :

Take the HangFire Code from GitHub which is opensource now

In the Dashboard Pages you will find FailedJobsPage.cshtml. Update this page contents with the short url that you want.

But this cshtml will not be rendered until you run the custom tool -  "razor generator tool"(VS Extension) for this cshtml page which generates cs file
You can see these cs files already present in the GitHub Code (expand the cshtml page you will find the cs file)

After finishing the above steps make sure the same path is configured in the DashboardRoutes.cs file as well.

=========================

"ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" in "handlers" section 
of SharePoint Application web Config is causing the actual issue